# Create "diff-based" pull request gate in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, pull-request

I have a gate (Build Verification / Status Check) that runs some benchmark tests I wrote. The benchmark runs the new code and returns the total run time of the new code.

Instead of a hard-coded threshold like "if the time is less than 10 seconds", I want to make this gate a diff-based metric, to see the % difference in run time between the newly proposed code and the result from the `main` branch commit that this branch came from (like usually done in Code Coverage gates)

Is there a built-in way to make a "diff-based" gate on Azure DevOps?

Comment: For the Pull Request Gate, do you mean that the Pull Request feature in Azure DevOps? As far as I know, Azure DevOps use branch policy to verify the pull request. If possible, can you share the current settings of the pull request gate?

Comment: Pull request gate - the Build Validation or Status Checks like Code Coverage. I want to create one that will verify the pull request but with % difference

Comment: In Azure DevOps, there is no built-in method can achieve it. For a workaround, we can setup Pipeline and Branch Policy -> Build Validation to get the similar feature. Please check the answer, I have shared some steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no built-in method can make a "diff-based" gate in Azure DevOps.

For a workaround, you can run the Pipeline through Build Validation in the Branch policy to obtain the running time of the Pull Ruqeust pre-merged code and the running time of the main branch. Finally, get the percentage through a custom script.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Create the Build Pipeline(YAML type) and use the [repo resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) to checkout the main branch of the current repo.

For example:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: mainbranchrepo
    type: git
    name: sqlite-dotnet-core.git
    ref: main
    

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
  path: s/PullRequest
- checkout: mainbranchrepo
  path: s/MainBranch
```

In this case, once the pipeline is triggered by Pull Request, it will checkout the pre-merged branch and main branch at the same time.

Step2: Add steps to run the benchmark tests on Pull Request Branch and the Main Branch. Then you can collect the two run time of the benchmark tests

Step3: Add custom script to get the percentage difference in run time.

For example:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: mainbranchrepo
    type: git
    name: sqlite-dotnet-core.git
    ref: main


pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
  path: s/PullRequest
- checkout: mainbranchrepo
  path: s/MainBranch
-  run benchmark tests on Pull Request Branch
-  run benchmark tests on Main Branch

- script: custom script to get the % result
```

Step4: Add Build Validation Branch Policy to use the YAML Pipeline above.

When the Pipeline is triggered by Pull Request, it will show the following branches:

[image]

Note: If you need to fail the Pipeline in custom script or pass the run time value to next tasks. You can use the [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't fully understand it. How can I use two `checkout` one after another and how can I run the benchmark tests in the right branch?

Comment: In the checkout step, we can set the path for each branch. Then the branches will be checkout to the separate folders.  When you run the benchmark tests, you can use code from a specific folder. For example: go to the target folder and run the benchmark test.

Comment: Since it comes from the same repo, the branch of the later checkout will overwrite the branch of the previous checkout if we don't set the path for the checkout branch. So this is required. The path value in the answer abobee: **s/PullRequest** = **$(build.sourcesdirectory)/PullRequest**

Comment: Ahh, now I understand. Thank you very much!